# Select folder path with writefile()

Tags: sqlite

I success to extract the content (blob) into a file. 
However, how to change the file destination to another folder ?

```
Attach database 'serverFilesDatabase.db' as db1;
Attach database 'ServerDatabase.db' as db2;
Select writefile((b.filename),(data)) from db1.files a inner join db2.filesTable b on a.fileId= b.fileId Limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague, find the solution for this problem under Windows :

```
Select writefile(( "C:\\MyPath\\" || b.filename),(data)) from db1.files a inner join db2.filesTable b on a.fileId= b.fileId Limit 1;
```

Comment: SQL does not use backslash escaping.